# Android compose Navigation and ViewModel constructor calls

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Currently I'm using compose with navigation and viewmodels.
The code of my NavHost is the following

```
composable(MyRoute.name + "/{param}") { backStackEntry ->
                    val param = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("id") ?: ""
                    val viewModel = hiltViewModel<MyViewModel>()
                    MyComposable(
                        viewModel = viewModel
                    )
                }
```

The issue I'm facing is that **viewModel.init** is called an infinite number of times (I guess it is recomposition), but the viewModel is supposed to have only one instance that outlives the lifecycle of the composables.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LaunchedEffect` to run your network call.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) for reference.

Comment: It has nothing to do with side effects, the viewmodel constructor is called an infinite number of times